# Alamofire crashes only when running archived app

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, alamofire

I am having an issue with my HTTP request using Alamofire. When I try to reproduce the issue with the XCode debugger it does not crashes but when I archive the app and run the .ipa file on my iPad with ios 10.0.2 I always get a crash.

This is an example of a call that crashes when running the arhived app:

```
static func loginOnServerUrl(serverURL: String, user: String, password: String,
        successCallback: ((JSON) -> Void)? = nil, failureCallback: ((Error) -> Void)? = nil){

            let params = [
                ApiParams.ACTION : "login",
                ApiParams.LoginParams.USER : user,
                ApiParams.LoginParams.PASSWORD : password,
            ]

        Alamofire.request("http://\(serverURL)/AppSrv", method: .get, parameters: params).responseJSON { response in
                switch response.result {
                case .success(let value):
                    //JSON raiz
                    let json = JSON(value)

                    for (key, value) in json.acceptingSigleValueAsArray {
                        log("\(key) : \(value)")
                    }


                     if let successCallback = successCallback {
                         successCallback(json)
                     }


                case .failure(let error):
                    log(error.localizedDescription)
                    if let failureCallback = failureCallback {
                        failureCallback(error)
                    }
                }
            }
    }
```

This is one of the crash logs I am getting:

```
Incident Identifier: ****
CrashReporter Key:   *****
Hardware Model:      iPad5,2
Process:             ****
Path:                ****
Identifier:         ****
Version:             1.42 (1.2.3a)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           ****


Date/Time:           2016-10-21 10:16:08.9811 +0200
Launch Time:         2016-10-21 10:16:06.2504 +0200
OS Version:          iPhone OS 10.0.2 (14A456)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000000059480bec8
Termination Signal: Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libswiftCore.dylib              0x0000000100e19b6c 0x100c38000 + 1973100
1   myapp                           0x00000001000c4d88 static ServerManager.(pingOnServerUrl(serverUrl : String, successCallback : (Int64) -> ()?, failureCallback : (Error) -> ()?) -> ()).(closure #1) (ServerManager.swift:0)
2   Alamofire                       0x00000001003aca84 specialized DataRequest.(response<A where ...> (queue : DispatchQueue?, responseSerializer : A, completionHandler : (DataResponse<A.SerializedObject>) -> ()) -> Self).(closure #1).(closure #1) (ResponseSerialization.swift:0)
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001889f1200 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
4   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001889f11c0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001889f5d6c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1000
6   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000189b15f2c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
7   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000189b13b18 __CFRunLoopRun + 1660
8   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000189a42048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
9   GraphicsServices                0x000000018b4c5198 GSEventRunModal + 180
10  UIKit                           0x000000018fa15628 -[UIApplication _run] + 684
11  UIKit                           0x000000018fa10360 UIApplicationMain + 208
12  myapp                           0x00000001000bf024 main (AppDelegate.swift:16)
13  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000188a245b8 start + 4

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000188b36a88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000188bf936c _pthread_wqthread + 1452
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000188bf8db4 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000188b36a88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000188bf936c _pthread_wqthread + 1452
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000188bf8db4 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000188bf8db0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000188bf8db0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000188b36a88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000188bf936c _pthread_wqthread + 1452
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000188bf8db4 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 6 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000188b1816c mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000188b17fdc mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000189b15cec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000189b13908 __CFRunLoopRun + 1132
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000189a42048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
5   Foundation                      0x000000018a550b1c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
6   Foundation                      0x000000018a57160c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 96
7   UIKit                           0x000000019038ac7c -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 136
8   Foundation                      0x000000018a64e50c __NSThread__start__ + 1024
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000188bfb860 _pthread_body + 240
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000188bfb770 _pthread_body + 0
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000188bf8dbc thread_start + 4

Thread 7 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000188b1816c mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000188b17fdc mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000189b15cec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000189b13908 __CFRunLoopRun + 1132
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000189a42048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
5   CFNetwork                       0x000000018a22fcec +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 336
6   Foundation                      0x000000018a64e50c __NSThread__start__ + 1024
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000188bfb860 _pthread_body + 240
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000188bfb770 _pthread_body + 0
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000188bf8dbc thread_start + 4

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000170246c30   x1: 0x0000000170246c30   x2: 0x0000000000000008   x3: 0x0000000188b7c250
    x4: 0x0000000100e099a4   x5: 0x0000000100df14f8   x6: 0x0000000000000065   x7: 0x0000000170287c78
    x8: 0x000000059480bea8   x9: 0x0000000ffffffff8  x10: 0x0000000000000001  x11: 0xbaddc0dedeadbead
   x12: 0x0000000000000177  x13: 0x0000000000000177  x14: 0x0000000100be6a30  x15: 0x0000000000000000
   x16: 0x0000000100e19b54  x17: 0xb000000000000003  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000000
   x20: 0x0000000100e94060  x21: 0x00000001ae195ef8  x22: 0x000000017046cf40  x23: 0xb000000000000003
   x24: 0x0000000000000000  x25: 0x0000000000000000  x26: 0x0000000000000004  x27: 0x0000000100be6a30
   x28: 0x0000000170246c30   fp: 0x000000016fd46b60   lr: 0x00000001000c4d88
    sp: 0x000000016fd46870   pc: 0x0000000100e19b6c cpsr: 0x20000000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change Swift Compiler optimization Level to

> Fast, Single File Optimization

instead of whole module!
[image: see the highlighted]
Something seems unusual with whole module optimization and Alamofire!